# Label items side by side and dropdown below the lable tag

Tags: html, css

I have 7 dropdowns in my webpage, I want to display lable tag side by and the dropdown below the respective lable.How to do this.

For example,

Filename

```
<option>1..</option>
<option>2..</option>

<option>3..</option>
<option>4..</option>


<select>
```

Browser

```
<option>chrome</option>
<option>firefox</option>

<option>...</option>
<option>...</option>
```

Here, I want to display as below,

```
Filename     Browser        ..         ..      ..
dropdown     dropdown       dropdown   ..      ..
```

how to do this?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Check out Bootstrap Grid System. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: just add some code snippet what you have done

Comment: If You are using Bootstrap  apply bootstrap <nav> bar or use grid System.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Filename</th>
                    <th>Browser</th>
                    <th>Value3</th>
                    <th>Value4</th>
                    <th>Value5</th>
                    <th>Value6</th>
                    <th>Value7</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name="filename">
                            <option>Value1</option>
                            <option>Value2</option>
                            <option>Value3</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <select name="browser">
                            <option>Chrome</option>
                            <option>Firefox</option>
                            <option>IE</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <select name="filename">
                            <option>Value1</option>
                            <option>Value2</option>
                            <option>Value3</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <select name="filename">
                            <option>Value1</option>
                            <option>Value2</option>
                            <option>Value3</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <select name="filename">
                            <option>Value1</option>
                            <option>Value2</option>
                            <option>Value3</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <select name="filename">
                            <option>Value1</option>
                            <option>Value2</option>
                            <option>Value3</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <select name="filename">
                            <option>Value1</option>
                            <option>Value2</option>
                            <option>Value3</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
               
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Filename</th>
                <th>Browser</th>
                <th>Value3</th>
                <th>Value4</th>
                <th>Value5</th>
                <th>Value6</th>
                <th>Value7</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="filename">
                        <option>Value1</option>
                        <option>Value2</option>
                        <option>Value3</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <select name="browser">
                        <option>Chrome</option>
                        <option>Firefox</option>
                        <option>IE</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <select name="filename">
                        <option>Value1</option>
                        <option>Value2</option>
                        <option>Value3</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <select name="filename">
                        <option>Value1</option>
                        <option>Value2</option>
                        <option>Value3</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <select name="filename">
                        <option>Value1</option>
                        <option>Value2</option>
                        <option>Value3</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <select name="filename">
                        <option>Value1</option>
                        <option>Value2</option>
                        <option>Value3</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <select name="filename">
                        <option>Value1</option>
                        <option>Value2</option>
                        <option>Value3</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap your `select`element inside a `label`. Then to put them side by side you need to use `display: inline-block` for `<label>`tags, and `display: block` for `<select>` tags.

```css
label { display: inline-block }
select { display: block }
```

```html
<label>Filename
  <select>
    <option>option one</option>
    <option>option two</option>
  </select>
</label>

<label>Browser
  <select>
    <option>option one</option>
    <option>option two</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting everything inside a `table` like shown below. The reason I am not using a `table` element but a `div` styled like a table is for possible responsive purposes.

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
<div class="cell">
<label>Filename</label>
<select>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
<option>Option 4</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="cell">
<label>Browser</label>
<select>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
<option>Option 4</option>
</select>
</div>
...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed; /* this will make all your cells equal*/
}
.cell {
  display:table-cell;
}
```

Here is a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scooterlord/19pbq1cc/

Depending on your `label` sizes you might want to add to the `.cell` css:

```
.cell {
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Also, for the `select` styling to make them all equal:

```
select {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
```

Updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/scooterlord/19pbq1cc/1/